# Getting an Instagram Access Token with Client ID, Client Secret and code

Tags: instagram, access-token

I'm trying to get an Instagram Developer Access Token. I have all needed information (Client ID, Client Secret and Code) and have input this into "Terminal" on my computer with the code, below. I am not getting anything back. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be inputing this information somewhere else to get the access token?

```
curl -F 'client_id=[CLIENT ID]
' \
-F 'client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]
' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=https://[MY WEBSITE]' \
-F 'code=[CODE]' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and click "Manage" next to your app.

- my "**Client ID**" is 11111111111111111111111111111111
- my "**Client Secret**" is 22222222222222222222222222222222
- my "**Valid redirect URIs**" under the "Security" tab is https://www.example.com/
- my "**code=**" value is received by going to this URL https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=11111111111111111111111111111111&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/&response_type=code . This redirects me to https://www.example.com/?code=33333333333333333333333333333333 and in that URL is my "code".

These have to be EXACT EXACT, including the redirect URL's trailing or non-trailing slash, caps, all that.

```
curl -F 'client_id=11111111111111111111111111111111' \
-F 'client_secret=22222222222222222222222222222222' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/' \
-F 'code=33333333333333333333333333333333' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

This will return a JSON object about your user, including the almighty "**access_token**". Mine is 44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444 .

You can then go to other endpoints like this one that gets me a JSON object about my recent posts https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444